# NameError: name 'ModelSelect2MultipleField' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an error when I run a program that says that `ModelSelect2MultipleField` is not defined. I use it here:

```
from django import forms
from django_select2 import *
from django.db.models import Q
from contacts.models import Contact
from cards.models import JobCard
from employee.models import *

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_fail_always(value):
    raise ValidationError(u'%s not valid. Infact nothing is valid!' % value)

########### Forms ##############]

class GetContactSearchForm(forms.Form):
    clients = ModelSelect2MultipleField(queryset=Contact.objects, required=False)

class GetEmployeeSearchForm(forms.Form):
    employees = ModelSelect2MultipleField(queryset=Employee.objects, required=False)
```

My version of `python` is `2.7.10` and my `django` is `1.8`; is there something I should replace that field with, or something else I need to install or put in my `settings.py` file?
Thanks!

Comment: Where did you import the `ModelSelect2MultipleSelect`?

Comment: I thought that it was imported with django_select2, but when I specifically type
    from django_select2 import ModelSelect2MultipleField
it gives me an error saying that it can't import it.

Comment: Where did you read about that field? The [docs for django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html) don't even mention any fields, they just have widgets.

Comment: I don't know if it actually is imported there; I was just guessing since the command imports everything from django_select2. If that's not the case, I'm not sure where ModelSelect2MultipleField would be, or if it's an outdated version of something else entirely

Comment: I tried to import it with from django_select2.fields because I saw that it worked for someone else, but now the error is that "there is no module named fields". 
my version of django_select2 is 5.8.9, by the way.