# ModelSelect2MultipleField not defined

Tags: python, django

Does anybody know where ModelSelect2MultipleField is imported from?
I've been trying to import it into a file that I need, and I thought that I could do it with

```
from django_select2.fields import ModelSelect2MultipleField
```

but I keep getting errors.
Before when I had it

```
from django_select2 import *
```

It said that ModelSelect2MultipleField, which I use in the py file, was not defined. Now it says that there is no module named fields.

The .py file I'm talking about can be found here (https://bitbucket.org/cbplusd/wibo/src/efc144e1bdc1eb52f76591c60ff0a1d40464b0ed/reports/forms.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

The Django-Select2 I have installed is version 5.8.9, so is there another way to import ModelSelect2MultipleField other than this way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, which got responses from the top Django answerer on Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707032/nameerror-name-modelselect2multiplefield-is-not-defined

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2MultipleWidget`. I found this by looking at the test application [here](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/blob/master/tests/testapp/forms.py).

There is no ModelSelect2MultipleField there is however a ModelSelect2MultipleWidget which should do what you need.

Comment: When I do that, it says that it cannot import ModelSelect2MultipleField, but the application you linked to said ModelSelect2MultipleWidget instead. Should I be using that? what's the difference between the two?

Comment: There is no `ModelSelect2MultipleField` it's `ModelSelect2MultipleWidget`. I updated my answer.

Comment: oh, okay. so that works, but if I originally had (queryset=Contact.objects, required=False), how do I adjust the keyword for required=False, because now I'm getting an error saying "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'". Tried changing it to 'required' = False, but now it says that the keyword can't be an expression

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise the form field as a Django widget and then specify the add-on widget in the parameters like so:

clients = ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Contact.objects, widget=Select2MultipleWidget())